# Сreate a signature field and fill it in

Tags: formatting, signatures

I would like to create a signature field like in the photo and make sure to fill it with text.
[image]

I tried to do this with

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\underset{\text{name of the faculty}}{\underline{\hspace{6.5cm}}}$
\end{document}
```

but I didn't understand how to fill in the field itself

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this in standalone? For a real document article is a better choice.  Or perhaps use a minipage or varwidth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\underset{\text{name of the faculty}}{\underline{\text{faculty of Mathematics and Mechanics}}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: it works very well, but how can I extend the line to the edges of the page?

Comment: ok, it works with ```$\underset{\text{name of the faculty}}{\underline{\text{\hspace{5cm}{faculty of Mathematics and Mechanics}\hspace{5cm}}}}$```